# How can I randomize a number within a range and make every number have equal probability

Tags: javascript

I was trying to make a randomizing array, but the thing is that the number 2 is chosen a lot (and it makes it Array[2]), here is my current code (it's rps):

```js
const rps = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']; 
//the next few lines are irrelevant
const chosen = rps[Math.round(Math.random()*3)-1] //usually returns Scissors
```

My goal is to find a way to randomize to have each of the choices with around 33% chance of being chosen (since 3 choices, 33.3%)

Comment: `rps[Math.floor(Math.random() * rps.length)]`

Comment: Use `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)` instead

Comment: Your code also tries to access `rps[-1]`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Interestingly, [`rps.at(Math.round(Math.random() * 3) - 1)`](//github.com/tc39/proposal-relative-indexing-method) would work just fine.

Comment: It didn't, it said rps.at is not a function, but I found a way to get them all around the same probability, I will post my answer
Edit: nvm the question got closed

Comment: Here's a distribution of the results: https://jsfiddle.net/uorg7xcq/